# How to select first element of series and reassign it to cell in data frame column with python

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I used `.str.split(" ")` to separate each cell in a column of a data frame into a series of three elements. I would like, for each row, to replace each cell with the first element of each series.

I have tried using:

```
df['number']=df['number'].str.split(" ")
df['number']=df['number'][0]
```

But this gives error:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

Some example code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Name':['1 Tim Tom', '2 Jack Jill', '3 Billy Bob', '4 Sally Sue'],'Letter': 
['A','B','C','D']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Name']=df['Name'].str.split(" ")
print(df)
```

Should produce:

```
              Name Letter
0    [1, Tim, Tom]      A
1  [2, Jack, Jill]      B
2  [3, Billy, Bob]      C
3  [4, Sally, Sue]      D
```

I want the result to be:

```
              Name Letter
0              [1]      A
1              [2]      B
2              [3]      C
3              [4]      D
```

Also what would I do if I wanted to assign cell 1, 2, or 3 of the list to a new column of the data frame? Like this:

```
  Name  Name2 Name3 Letter
0  [1]    Tim   Tom      A
1  [2]   Jack  Jill      B
2  [3]  Billy   Bob      C
3  [4]  Sally   Sue      D
```

Comment: Hi thefirstreal, You recently asked a question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64280368/use-python-to-drop-columns-in-dataframe-that-meet-two-specific-criterion#64280368 . I wrote the answer in a comment since someone closed the question for answers even though is was perfectly understandable. But then the question was entirely deleted. I am contacting you here as I spent some time finding the answer and don't want to lose the effort: Parentheses were missing around the subconditions: `df.drop((df[(df['Age'] >= 25.0) | (df['Weight'] >= 200.0)]).index, inplace=True)`.

Comment: I appreciate you doing so. I have un-deleted the question so hopefully it will open back up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by setting expand = True in .split(). This will create a new column for each element that is split on. You can then assign these new columns to your original df.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Name':['1 Tim Tom', '2 Jack Jill', '3 Billy Bob', '4 Sally Sue'],'Letter': 
['A','B','C','D']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df[['Name','Name2','Name3']] = df['Name'].str.split(" ", expand=True)
print(df)
```

Sources: 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html
https://youtu.be/vPKwm1XZjp8

Comment: I am getting this error with my main code: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: This can happen if you try to apply  .str() to a DataFrame object  like so:   df.str()      instead of the column of a DataFrame   like so: df['col_name'].str()

Comment: Thanks, I removed an extra set of brackets which was also causing the error around the column. Now I am getting a new error: "ValueError: Columns must be same length as key"

Comment: I fixed this by adding onto the resultant columns until it worked. There was two places the split occurred and I needed two more columns which are now empty.

Comment: Depending on your needs you could add the argument n=2 (....str.split(" ", n=2, inplace=True). This will only make a maximum of 2 splits (so you would get 3 elements). This however, will add any extra elements to your last column.

Comment: Yes this is what I'd like to do. But I get: TypeError: split() got an unexpected keyword argument 'inplace'

Answer (score 0):

for the first question you can use:

df['Name'] = df['Name'].str[0]

Comment: This will only work if your first numbers are only 1 digit long. If you had a value of 11 this method would assign the column value to be 1.

Comment: I used the example of @thefirstreal where the cell is already split in a list by df['Name']=df['Name'].str.split(" ") if you keep the string you are definitely right